# How to adjust weight of profile 2 fields

Tags: users

I added some fields to the default user registration form. I then installed the [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) Module through which I added three (3) fields- "first name", "surname" and "place of work".

Is there a way to make the first name and surname fields appear above the default user registration fields while the place of work appears below it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [Drupal Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to achieve that.

You basically need to alter the structure of the form before it gets rendered.

If you are using the [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module, the best way to go about it would be to implement `hook_form_profile2_edit_PROFILE_TYPE_form_alter()`in a custom module.

You will then need to transform the `$form` array as needed (change field weights, and field positions).

For example:

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_profile2_edit_YOUR_PROFILE_TYPE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Apply transformations to $form
  // e.g. change field weights
  $form['your_custom_profile_type']['place_of_work']['#weight'] = '-10';

  // e.g. copy field into new position
  $form['account']['place_of_work'] = $form['your_custom_profile_type']['place_of_work'];

  // Add a custom pre_render function to prevent the field from showing up again in the form
  $form['#pre_render'][] = 'MODULE_NAME_pre_render';
}
```

The pre_render function could look like this:

```
function MODULE_NAME_pre_render(&$form) {
  // Prevent custom field from displaying twice
  unset($form['your_custom_profile_type']['place_of_work']);
  return $form;
}
```